# my accuracy score yields 0.0, any ideas as to how to solve this? Thanks

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Samuel Mireku/Desktop/pokemon_data.csv')

#data shape(800, 12)
print(df.shape)

#CHECKING FOR NULLS AND SUM OF NULLS
print(df.iloc[0:12].isnull())
print(df.isnull().sum())

#removes nulls
print(df.dropna(inplace=True))

print(df['Type 2'])

#removal of nulls brought shape to 414, 12
print(df.shape)
print(df.columns)

#dropped '#' column
print(df.drop(['#'], axis=1))

#encoding
var_mod = ['Name', 'Type 1', 'Type 2', 'HP', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Sp. Atk',
       'Sp. Def', 'Speed', 'Generation', 'Legendary']
le = LabelEncoder()
for i in var_mod:
    df[i] = le.fit_transform(df[i])

from sklearn.model_selection import  train_test_split

X = df.iloc[0:12]
y = df.iloc[12]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=5)

print(X_train)
print(y_train)
print(X_test)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

#Create a Gaussian Classifier
clf = GaussianNB()

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.predict(X_test)
clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Out[91]: 0.0 is my accuracy score

My accuracy score yields 0.0, any ideas as to how to solve this? Have not had any luck scouring the web for answers. Please bear in mind that i am new to do this. could the encoding be the issue? I opted for the encoding because this was error I was receiving prior to encoding:

> 'ValueError: could not convert string to float:'

Comment: It looks like it could be an encoding issue. Instead of using `le.fit_transform(df[i])` on each label, just call it on the entire  `var_mod` list.

Comment: 'just call it on the entire var_mod list'. elaborate please. Thank you

Comment: You could try data scaling, stratified K fold for class imbalance, sampling, different classifiers and metrics if that helps. Could you post the dataset csv?